# Using JQuery within an HREF link

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to use the following action which works fine in console but i'd like to have it fire when a link is clicked.

Code:

```
$('#angrid656 > div.angrid > div:nth-child(2) > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td.angrid-item-buttons.ng-scope > a.btn.btn-info.btn-accent.opacity75').click()
```

I've created the link like this but it's not working properly:

```
<a href="$('#angrid656 > div.angrid > div:nth-child(2) > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td.angrid-item-buttons.ng-scope > a.btn.btn-info.btn-accent.opacity75').click()"><div class="title">[Title]</div></a>
```

Comment: that's not angular code, that's jquery.

Comment: @Claies appologies updated the title

Comment: can you add more of your HTML and describe what it is you are actually trying to accomplish?  If you are using Angular, there are way easier ways to handle things like opacity, and there are surely better ways to do this in jquery as well.  If you are indeed using Angular, you ***should not be trying to use jquery at all***

Comment: That is pretty much my code. I have a button elsewhere on my page which is the #angrid656 element. I'm trying to create a link elsewhere on the page that when pressed will actually simulate a click on this other button that is hidden with CSS.

Comment: When i execute the top line of code through console it clicks my button, which is all i'm looking to do. I'd like to do this at the press of a button instead of pasting it into console.

Comment: it really feels like this isn't the best way to accomplish what you are describing, but only seeing a single `<a>` element and not knowing if you are really running Angular, or Jquery, or both, it's hard to know for sure.  However, if you change it to `<a href="javascript:yourcodehere">` (add `javascript:` to the beginning), it *should* work....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to execute Javascript in an `href` attribute, you have to begin with `javascript:`

```
<a href="javascript:$('#angrid656 > div.angrid > div:nth-child(2) > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td.angrid-item-buttons.ng-scope > a.btn.btn-info.btn-accent.opacity75').click()">...</a>
```

It doesn't matter whether it's plain Javascript or jQuery (which is just a library of Javascript functions).

You can also use an `onclick` attribute, and use `href="#"` to prevent the link from going anywhere automatically.